# Mailgun & CI / PHP

Tags: php, email

Looking at Mailgun as a good solution for sending HTML email to a large number of recipients

How would this be implemented with CI?

Comment: Please try to find out by yourself first. If you cannot figure out how something works, ask here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use MailGun's [SMTP delivery](http://documentation.mailgun.net/quickstart.html#sending-messages) with the standard Codeigniter [Email library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html) configured for SMTP.

I did something similar with SendGrid recently . Worked a treat with Sendgrid, didn't have to worry about anything apart from authentication to their smtp server. Sendgrid handled the quantity without any problem (though it was way less recipients - about 1k).

Comment: Right, thanks for pointing that out! a much easier approach. I would just set the SMTP settings in the CI email config file and then be able to use the CI Email library like usual. Sweet.

Comment: Good luck.. and Test Test Test before you send!